# mapping iphone uuid to phone number

Tags: push-notification, uuid, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am developing an mdm server to interact with apple push notification service. When I install a configuration profile on an iPhone, the device pushes the UUID and push magic string to the server. My goal is to install configuration porofiles on large number of iPhones. On the server side I don't know the UDID phone number mapping, All I have is phone number. How to I map the UUID to the phone number.

When I send a push notification I have to use UUID, to send correct push command on qualified devices, I need the UUID vs phone number mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a device registers with your MDM system you will know that device's UDID (unique device identifier). You can then send a `DeviceInformation` command to the device and get the phone number (if, in fact, the device has a phone number). You will save that phone number in the database in a record associated with the UDID you got when the device initially enrolled in your MDM.

From this point on, whenever you send a command to the device that command will have a UUID. Make sure your system remembers the UDID of the device that you are sending this command to.  When the device responds that response will contain this UUID and using this UDID you can then look up the UDID (and hence the phone number) of the device that responded.

Note: If you are trying to use the phone number as a unique identifier for an enrolled device, don't. Use the UDID instead.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am developing this solution in java using javapns. Do you have any idea how to send the DeviceInformation payload using javapns?

Comment: No. We have a PHP implementation written from scratch that uses the `stream_context_create` function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the DeviceUUID for push notifications, you neet one of the two deviceTokens (sandbox or distribution) generated by Apple.

After getting the deviceToken from Apple in the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

you have to register your device at your server and also send the phoneNumber.
I don't see an other option.

Comment: We are looking for solution where we don't install an app but install a configuration profile with an MDM payload. When I do this, I get the initial sync on the mdm server with pushMagic string UDID and token. This token is not in 64 bit format as required by APN service. Apart from that, I need to map this token/UDID to a phone number so that I can store the mapping for further use( we store phone number in our DB). Is this solution feasible? I want to avoid creating an app if possible.